# Google Spreadsheet - How to split delimited text into columns without format conversions (i.e. preserve raw text)

Tags: google-sheets, split

Say...

cell 1 contains this text: `03400561, 1995-12-31`

I need a way to split this cell into 2 raw text columns". i.e.

My expected/wanted output: cell 2 = `03400561` (as text) and cell 3 = `1995-12-31` (as text)

If I use the `split` function to do this (e.g. cell 2 = `split(cell1,",")`), it removes leading zero, and convert the yyyy-mm-dd text into a google date. I do not wish to have this conversion to take place. i.e. I just wanted straight and simple split a text, into columns of text (not numbers. not dates).

How do I do this out of the box? (I've tried google around but no luck). Is this even possible?

Side note: the "Data" => "Split text into columns" approach - no luck. It converts all numeric-like texts into numbers, and date-like texts into dates. I wish to have raw text throughout and no conversion like this to happen. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly as hell, but seems to work on your example. Basically enclose the separator with double quotation marks to force sheets into interpreting the data as text. Then remove them and use `arrayformula()` to cover all the columns:

`=arrayformula(substitute(SPLIT(char(34)&substitute(U19,",",char(34)&","&char(34))&char(34),",",true,false),char(34),""))`

`CHAR(34)` evaluates to double quotation (i.e. ") to signify text entry. Just be aware that the second variable includes a leading space (' 1995-12-31')

Comment: Thank you so much for the super speedy answer! I have just tested this out on a real case string (with 28 elements in the delimited string), used your formula, and replaced `U19` in your formula with the cell that corresponds to the delimited string. Works! (I then did a one off copy and paste as values to get rid of the formula). Thanks so much again you have just solved a problem that I've had for ages! :)